# How to fix the footer section in this CSS file?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am a new ASP.NET developer and this is my first time to work with CSS file. I have a simple CSS file and I am struggling with footer part.
The footer looks like following:

[image]

I need to modify it in such a way:

1. that will be a little space between the text and the borders
2. Also, I don't know how to make text in the middle as centered. I am
   using float but it still shows like this.
3. I need the footer width to be fixed as sometimes the border of footer goes out of the border of the body.

Here's my css code:

```
.footer
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 1250px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
}

.footer p.left {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}

.footer p.right {
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}

.footer p.centered {
    text-align:center;
}
```

And here's my ASP.NET code:

```
<div class="footer">
             <p class="left">
                 Copyright For MyCompany <%= DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() %>. All Rights Reserved
             </p>
             <p class="right">
                 Developed by <strong>IBM/STAD/PSD</strong>
             </p>
                           <p class="centered">
                Last update: 10/23/2013 02:42 PM 
                <br />
                 For any issue/comments Contact <a href="mailto:Test">
                    The Administrator (Test)</a>
              </p>   

          </div>
```

Would you kindly help me in resolving these two issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add padding to the footer, e.g. `padding:10px;`
2. Set the margin to `margin:0 auto;` on `p.centered` instead of floating it
3. Set the footer to be fixed, add: `position:fixed; left:0px; bottom:0px;` to your footer.

I also used the [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) property so that you can set the width of the footer to 100% of the screen width without losing the borders.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/W5sUS/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. However, I have another class called container which includes the whole body of the website and its width is 1250px
`.conainer
{
    width: 1250px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    display: table;
}`

**How can I make it and the footer as well fixed with the same width?**

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I have to keep the width of the whole website as 1250px as much as possible. That's why I want it to be fixed including the footer

Comment: I've updated my jsFiddle. Is this what you want? I set the margins of `body` and `html` to 0 then added `box-sizing` to the container too.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go here, I did it like this: (it performs well with any length inputs, although I'm not sure what you want to happen when the right or left blocks get too large.)

```
.footer p.left { text-align: left; float: left; margin-left: 10px; }
.footer p.right { float: right; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; }
.footer p.centered { text-align: center; clear:both; position: relative; top: -12px; }
```